# How to write function signature for accepting std::vector of any type?

Tags: c++, stdvector

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-vector) helpfully shows how to print a `std::vector` to `std::out`. I've tried making a generic function for printing vectors of any kind:

something like this:

```
  void MyClass::print_vector(const std::vector<auto> vec) {
      for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
          std::cout << *i << ' ';
      std::cout << std:: endl;
  }
  std::vector<int> my_vec = {1, 2, 3};
  print_vector(my_vec);
```

This builds and runs as expected (at least for `std::vector<int>`) but does trigger a build warning:

```
warning: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with ‘-fconcepts’
```

what is the proper way to do this in c++14?

Comment: You can use a function template instead. I.e. `template<class T> void print_vector(const std::vector<T> &vec) ...`.

Comment: Why would you artificially restrict it to vectors? `template <typename CT> void print_vector<CT& const vec>` would also accept `std::list<float>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually, no. GCC provides it as an extension, but it's not valid C++20.

Comment: @cigien https://stackoverflow.com/a/62516358/4386278

Comment: Rule of thumb: if the syntactical structure is the same, but the types vary, it's a template. Terse notation or not, it's still a template. And in C++14, you need a `template` head.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes, what about it? `void f(auto)` is certainly legal. But `void f(vector<auto>)` is not, which is what the OP is showing, and what I assume Jarod42 is referring to.

Comment: @cigien So it can _only_ be `auto` or `type-constraint auto`? That's a shame

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings For the moment, yeah. There'll be a new standard out in 3 years. So fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go simple and use auto deduction:

```
template <typename Container>
void print(const Container& c)
{
   for (const auto& e : c) cout << e << ' ';
   cout << endl;
}
```

This will accept any container for any type with defined `operator<<` for its elements.

One could also use type traits to enable/disable overloads for different containers.

For example, lets say we have type traits `IsContainer` defined as below.
Then one could do something like:

```
template <typename Container,
          typename = enable_if_t<IsContainer<Container, std:::vector>::value>>
void print(const Container& c)
{
   for (const auto& e : c) cout << e << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

with `IsContainer` type traits available to check for specific container type:

```
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
struct IsContainer: std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct IsContainer<Ref<Args...>, Ref>: std::true_type {};
```

This would be usable if you'd need more such checks in your project.

By using OR'ing one could also enable this for different containers with not replicating the code. For example to enable printing for `vector` and `list`:

```
 template <typename Container,
              typename = enable_if_t<
                  IsContainer<Container, std:::vector>::value
               || IsContainer<Container, std::list>::value>>
  void print(const Container& c)
  {
       for (const auto& e : c) cout << e << ' ';
        cout << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Well I think in the case of printing, that is basically what you probably want.

Comment: The issue with this is that it is a viable overload of `print` for every type, even those that aren't `for`able

Comment: one can trimm it down using type traits. By using OR'ing one could also enable this for different containers with not replicating the code. see the update.

Answer (score 2):

This is what templates supposed to do.

```
template <typename T>
void MyClass::print_vector(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << std:: endl;
}

std::vector<int> my_vec = {1, 2, 3};
print_vector(my_vec);
```